# Is it possible to have a generic codebehind c# file on aspx pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" EnableEventValidation="false"
AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="genericfile.cs" %>
```

Is it possible to use this to run the same piece of code on multiple pages?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I suspect this is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Common code can be encapsulated in a base page that all your pages inherit from.

Comment: Having worked on a project that took this approach in the past, I can tell you from personal experience that this is almost certainly a Very Bad Idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, it is possible**, just be sure that you are pointing the same file in the  `CodeFile` attribute and the `Inherits` has the same value than your original file

```
CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default"
```

also you **must delete the `.designer.cs` and the `.cs` files** that visual studio created before.

Just one last thing **be careful with the controls in the pages**, because if you have one control in one page and change its text on an event, and then in the other page there isn't that control, the page is going to throw an error